# function ts_rank_cd(text, tsquery) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm using full text search supported by postgres, I installed `acts_as_tsearch` plugin and it works successfully, but when I tried it later I found an error

> runtimeError: ERROR C42883 Mfunction ts_rank_cd(text, tsquery) does
>   not exist HNo function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type

Answer (score 8):

You need to cast your first parameter into a tsvector.

So let's assume you're searching against a column named `foo.text`. You will want to change from this:

```
SELECT ts_rank_cd(foo.text, plainto_tsquery('my search terms')) FROM foo;
```

to this:

```
SELECT ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(foo.text), plainto_tsquery('my search terms')) FROM foo;
```

or something similar.

If you're using the `@@` operator elsewhere, you can generally re-use the expressions that operator is operating on.

You can find more documentation on `to_tsvector` at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-DOCUMENTS

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

> ts_rank_cd(text, tsquery) does not
>   exist

This means there is no function with this name that accepts text and a tsquery parameter as input. And that's correct, PostgreSQL doens't have a function using these parameters.

From [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-textsearch.html):

> ts_rank_cd([ weights float4[], ]
>   vector tsvector, query tsquery [,
>   normalization integer ])

Change your input for the function ts_rank_cd() and you will be fine.